# Is "flewed down" an attempt at past imperfect?

Tags: past-tense

From a non-native speaker of English: "My friends have flewed down for my surgery." Is this is attempt at past imperfect? I am not sure, since the intent is to indicate the very recent past. Does English have a variation of the past tense to indicate the recent past, other than the use "just", as in "My friends have just flown down for my surgery."?

Comment: I think you meant to say "past perfect". *My friends had flown down*. WS2 is correct when he points out the participle  of the verb *fly* is *flown*.

Comment: Nope, no native speaker, even children, would make that mistake.

Comment: @Mitch: right … the mistake children make when they're learning to talk is to treat *fly* as a regular verb and say *flied*.

Comment: Usually. But [*my 2 yr old nephew, Jason was there and witnessed the resuscitaion attempts, and later told my Mom, that "one night a big, beautiful angel lady came and put wings on Macy Cole's back and **they flewed away**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+eleventh+hour%22&biw=1137&bih=869&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1600%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1799&tbm=bks#tbm=bks&q=%22they+flewed+away%22&tbas=0)

Comment: I think it should be noted that *flew* is also the past tense of fly (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flew) e.g. "A bird flew through my window this morning"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Flewed' does not exist as an inflection/participle of *fly*.

Its past participle is *flown*.

There is also no such thing as a 'past imperfect' in English, though the imperfect always implies a past action - *I was flying*.

No I can't think of any tense, or expression, which would incorporate the meaning of *something has just happened*.

If French is your language, you have the *venir de + infinitive* construction *Mes amis viennent d'accourir en avion pour me visiter*. ("My friends have just flown in to visit me") Perhaps that is what you were looking for, but unfortunately it doesn't exist in English.